# Which exception to throw when sequence lengths are not the same

Tags: c#, exception

I re-implemented [`Enumerable.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698) (mine is called `Merge`). It is the same as the original, except if one enumerator's `MoveNext` returns false before the other (indicating the sequences are not of the same length), it throws an exception.

My question is: What would be the most appropriate exception from the [BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Libraryhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library) to throw here? (I want this to closely mimic the rest of the `Enumerable` (LINQ) functions.)

Comment: First person who wants an exception with a perfect one.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that since your second array will be an argument. So

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Subclass of ArgumentException that’s thrown when a (usually numeric) argument is too big or too small. For example, this is thrown when passing a negative number into a function that accepts only positive values.

OR may be

```
System.InvalidOperationException
```

Thrown when the state of an object is unsuitable for a method to successfully execute, regardless of any particular argument values. Examples include reading an unopened file or getting the next element from an enumerator where the underlying list has been modified partway through the iteration.

Comment: FWIW: I went with `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.